# How can selenium click the button via x,y position

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found the button's x.y position via opencv function `matchTemplate()`,and now how can I click the button via its x,y position?

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are using selenium then you can find the element(in your case Button) using selenium apis and then click on it. No need to use opencv for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebDriver, we can use Actions

```
 new Actions(oWebDriver).moveByOffset(100, 200).click().build().perform();
```

where 100, 200 are x and y axis.

Answer (score 0):

You are 2 ways

1. Scroll till view and click

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(locator values);
   jsExec.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", elementToClick);
   jsExec.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
   ```
2. Scroll for a specific limit and click on the element

   ```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 250)", "");
   WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(locator values);
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
   ```